# how to join 2 python lists by selecting the position randomly but without changing the order

Tags: python, list, random, indexing

I want to join 2 python lists by selecting index randomly without changing the order,

```
a=(1,2,3,4,5)
b=(a,b,c,d)
```

to one of these randomly

```
final = (a,b,1,c,2,3,4,d,5)
final = (1,a,b,2,c,3,4,d,5)
final = (a,b,c,1,2,d,3,4,5)
```

etc.

Comment: That isn't "joining" them; it's *interleaving* them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```py
from random import shuffle

a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b = ("a", "b", "c", "d")


out = [iter(a)] * len(a) + [iter(b)] * len(b)
shuffle(out)

out = [next(i) for i in out]
print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 'd', 3, 4, 5]
```

---

The *trick* here is not to shuffle directly the values but iterators over the two tuples. First we populate the output list with **two** iterators which are referenced `len(a) + len(b)` times. Shuffle the list and use `next()` function over the iterators to obtain the real values in order.

Comment: That's a neat trick, but it should probably be explained in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

Pseudocode

```
list_a_index = 0
list_b_index = 0
new_list = []
for i in range(len(list_a) + len(list_b)):
    which_list = chooseRandomList() #get random A or B
    if (which_list == list_a)
        new_list.append(list_a[list_a_index])
        list_a_index++
    #and the same for list_b
    ...
```

and make sure that you consider the current indices for `list_a` and `list_b` while you choose the next random list to pull value from to not go index out of range.